# How to allow users to build a custom order or quote

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a site where I need to allow users to build a custom quote and then submit this quote. The end result could be as simple as an email to the site owner detailing what options the customer selected. Essentially it needs to work in a similar way an e-commerce system but without the checkout stage.

The user will select one of three plans first of all, then choose whether they'd like any add-ons (around 20 add-ons available). Finally they would enter a few of their own details and then click submit. The trouble is I've no idea how to go about building this.

Can anyone point me in the direction of where to start or does anyone know of any existing plugins that can do this type of thing already?

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Tom

Comment: This is outside of the scope of SO, check the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page. But to help, if you're using WordPress look into Gravity Forms. If not, google around for a form builder as this is what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said this post is a little open-ended, and not really ideal for Stack overflow.

That said, to point you in a direction (not necessarily the right one), you seem to be talking about building a form and submitting the results somehow. There are countless ways of doing this but a good place to start would be PHP - this would allow you to build forms and store the results.

Not a great answer I know but if you provide some more details I'd be happy to try and elaborate.

Comment: Thanks for your response and apologies this is too open-ended for Stack Overflow. I was struggling with how to go about this one or even what to ask so the suggestion provided is helpful. I'll explore using a form solution to solve this one.

Comment: No need to apologise - I just wanted to let you know that you may not get too many useful answers from here as SO tends to be best for very specific questions